# Changing ClickOnce Application to Normal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I recently programmed an application with c# and I was wondering if it is possible to change from ClickOnce to a normal Windows Application without clickonce because everytime the program starts up an irritating Window pops up like so:
   [image]

Edit:

I forgot to mention that it also irritates me that when you install the program in the program files it shows itself as a 'ClickOnce Application Reference' Is there any other way to have the files set out?

For example if I were to create a professional program and I wouldn't want the user to know ClickOnce was used but instead I used Dlls and Exe's, How would this be possible?

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more information about your application? Which type of the project it has? Is it some MS Office extension or usual .NET Windows Application?

Comment: Just a usual .Net windows application, im creating an application that allows the user to customise his/her desktop more, This will be able to update itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClickOnce is a deployment method; in itself it doesn't change your code or your application.  In that sense, you don't need to "change" anything to make the app non-click-once.

You can disable the publishing settings of your application entirely and just distribute the build outputs yourself, or create an installer - or disable the ClickOnce "check for updates" feature, which is accessible through the project properties screen (Publish tab, click "Updates...").

Comment: Alright Thanks for that, i forgot to mention that it also irritates me that when you install the program in the program files it shows itself as a 'ClickOnce Application Reference' Is there anyother way to have the files set out? For example if i were to create a professional program and I wouldn't want the user to know ClickOnce was used but instead i used Dlls and Exe's, How would this be possible?

Comment: Dlls and Exes are still used in ClickOnce, and the files are still laid out - they're just laid out with a different mechanism, and it's no less professional than any other.  If you wanted to not use ClickOnce, you probably want to look into an installer technology like InstallShield - the "Lite" version of which is part of VS2010 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm quite new to all of this so i really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: That's a pretty late downvote - care to explain, whoever that was?